# Show NSAlert on specific launches

Tags: cocoa, compare, nsalert

I need to show an `NSAlert` on the 3rd, 10th and 20th launch of the app, so far I have tried:

```
/* Note that the kLaunchCount is incremented as a Number in a dictionary */
if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kLaunchCount"] intValue] == 1||2||3)
{
    /* show the NSAlert */
}
```

The above code shows the `NSAlert` every launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code parses as `...||2||3`, which will always return true (since anything `|| 2` is true).  You should put the launch count into a variable `n` and then use `n == 3 || n == 10 || n == 20` as the test.